# In "spawn" multiprocessing, process for Python3 to load function internal to a module for execution

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-multiprocessing, spawn

Kindly note, all the description below is w.r.t. "spawn" method of multiprocessing (for compatibility with Windows).

When multiprocessing is set to "spawn" method, a new process is loaded from the main file. This is one of the first info to find by searching online.

I'm trying to dig deeper, and speed up the loading of a new Process (whenever it's created).
Here's some idea on how my project is structured:

```
<root>
<root>/main.py

<root>/modules/__init__.py
<root>/modules/app/__init__.py
<root>/modules/app/app.py

<root>/modules/app/middleware/__init__.py
<root>/modules/app/middleware/middleware.py
```

Now, when I try to create a process inside of `middleware.py`, it tries to load everything from main.py (and a lot of unnecessary modules gets loaded up, which slows down the loading process for process in middleware.py).

In my code a lot of extra libraries are also imported in main.py, and app.py, which slows down the first time loading the process craeted in middleware.py. But these extra modules aren't required to run the process created in middleware.py

1) How can I possibly make the loading of middleware.py as fast as possible (at the time of first launch of Process). And is it possible to directly load the middleware module in this new Process, rather than having everything load from main.py ?

2) I experimented by conditionally not loading app.py inside main.py (and hence middleware.py) whenever main.py is run as `__mp_main__`. I was expecting this to result in middleware.py never being loaded in the child process. But I still notice that middleware.py gets loaded. How is this possible?

Comment: Then either move your multiprocessing code *out* of that package structure to a place you can import from without having to load the rest of the project, or restructure the rest of your project to not load so much at import time, and defer loading of heavy resources. There is no one-size-fits-all quick solution here.

Comment: How about (2) btw.. I put a conditional check, which leaves out loading of app module whenever main.py is run in child process. But still app module, and hence middleware module is getting loaded. How is this possible?